# MarkLogic search and retrieve specific fields

Tags: java, marklogic

I am faily new to MarkLogic (and noSQL) and currently trying to learn the Java API client. My question on searching, which returns back search result snippets / matches, is it possible for the search result to include **specific fields** in the document?

For example, given this document:

```
{"id":"1", "type":"classified", "description": "This is a classified type."}
```

And I search using this:

```
    QueryManager queryMgr = client.newQueryManager();       
    StringQueryDefinition query = queryMgr.newStringDefinition();       
    query.setCriteria("classified");
    queryMgr.search(query, resultsHandle);
```

How can I get the JSON document's 3 defined fields (id, type, description) as part of the search result - so I can display them in my UI table?

Do I need to hit the DB again by loading the document via URI (thus if I have 1000 records, that means hitting the DB again 1000 times)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several options to retrieve specific fields with your search results.  You could use the [Pojo Data Binding Interface](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/binding).  You could [read multiple documents matching a query](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/bulk#id_37758) which brings back the entirety of each document which you can then get as a pojo or String or any other handle.  Or you can use the same API you're using above but add search options to allow you to [extract a portion of a matching document](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/searches#id_90087).

If you're bring back thousands of matches, you're probably not showing all those snippets to end users, so you should probably [disable snippets](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/query-options#id_58295) using something like

```
<transform-results apply="empty-snippet" />
```

in your options.

Comment: Thanks mate, I've used the approach on the link for "read multiple documents matching a query", wherein I get the contents of the document through the DocumentPage and DocumentRecord.getAsContent(Class).